# Sequence of operation in Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I took the example code from [npmjs > jsdom](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom). This process is performed in a few seconds and only after it I want to run a second action, such as **console.log**. But do not insert the  code in the body of jsdom. Maybe it's work with **Node.js > Stream** 
Whant to create a chain of functions, next process start as soon as the end of the previous.

Where i can read about sequence in Node.js?

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

jsdom.env({
  url: "http://news.ycombinator.com/",
  scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  done: function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function() {
      console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
  }
});

console.log("The end");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`Async.js`](https://github.com/caolan/async).

To be specific, you're looking for its [`series()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#series) functionality (`Run an array of functions in series, each one running once the previous function has completed`).

Code example (based on it's docs):

```
async.series([
    function(callback){
        jsdom.env({
  url: "http://news.ycombinator.com/",
  scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
  done: function (errors, window) {
    var $ = window.$;
    console.log("HN Links");
    $("td.title:not(:last) a").each(function() {
      console.log(" -", $(this).text());
    });
callback(null, 'one');
  }
});
    },
    function(callback){
        // do some more stuff (second task) ...
        callback(null, 'two');
    }
],
// optional callback
function(err, results){
    console.log("The end");
});
```