# How to defer a call in Backbone on completion of several asynchronous calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

If I have a backbone collection that has a method that calls an asynchronous method on each of its models like this:

```
getStatus: function() {
  this.each(function(model) {
    model.getStatus();
  });
}
```

And in the model class, an asynchronous ajax call is made like this:

```
getStatus: function() {
  $.ajax({
    //ajax properties here
  });
}
```

How can I determine when each and every model has completed it's asynchronous call (not necessarily successfully) and returned?

So in my collection, I need a `getStatusSuccess` method that executes after all these asynchronous calls have been completed. I have looked into [jQuery deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), and I have tried a few things to get it to work, but to no avail. However, I still believe that it can be solved using deferreds.

Comment: have model.getStatus return the `jqXHR`, replace each with map, return the return value from model.getStatus() to the map, then pass the array of jqXHR objects into $.when using .apply.

Comment: *"I have looked into jQuery deferreds, and I have tried a few things to get it to work, but to no avail."* your question would be better if you included a few of the things you tried, most likely one of them were close enough that we can fix it for you without having to build something for you.

Comment: @KevinB your first comment sufficed in answering the question without having to "build something for [me]". I didn't include the deferred because I was looking for open-ended solutions that did not necessarily use deferreds. Anyway, you can include your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) returns a Deferred object
- you can combine Deferred objects with [`jQuery.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) to produce a "master" Deferred

  > In the case where multiple Deferred objects are passed to jQuery.when, the method returns the Promise from a new "master" Deferred object that tracks the aggregate state of all the Deferreds it has been passed.
  >   The method will resolve its master Deferred as soon as all the
  >   Deferreds resolve, or reject the master Deferred as soon as one of the
  >   Deferreds is rejected.
- Backbone proxies a lot of functions from Underscore on collections, notably [`_.invoke`](http://underscorejs.org/#invoke) which returns an array with the results of the calls
- [`function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) will let you call a function with a given context and arguments provided as an array

Combining all this :

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    getStatus: function() {
        return $.ajax({
            // ...
        });
    }
});
var C = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: M,
    getStatus: function() {
        var jqXHRs = this.invoke('getStatus');
        return $.when.apply(this, jqXHRs);
    }
});

var c = new C([
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
]);
c.getStatus().always(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nKDjW/

Answer (score 0):

Check my recent answer at [Sequence of operation in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18160666/286260).

Basically you could use [Async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async). Check its [parallel](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) function..

Answer (score 0):

Can suggest two ways to defer a call:

1. jQuery `$.when()` construction, which is perfectly described above by [nikoshr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1071630/nikoshr)
2. or Underscore [`_.after(count, function)`](http://underscorejs.org/#after) method, which takes basically two arguments: amount of asynchronous calls and your call to defer.